# Remix routing v2 system

Tags: remix.run

I'm new to remix and I face an issue regarding the v2 routes system.

I try the v2 that keep all the routes to the base folder but with a lot of routes is very confusing.
So I prefer to split the routes with folders convention that match my app use cases.

I try to implement it base on [folders-for-organization](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/file-conventions/routes#folders-for-organization) but didn't succeed.

So to workaround with the old way(v1) I use the package `"@remix-run/v1-route-convention": "^0.1.4"` and add a config in remix.

If someone could help me with it.

To help you with the answer I create this stackblitz base on the remix tutorial template
https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-sxej2u?file=app%2Froot.tsx

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `remix.config`, if you're using any convention other than the default (v2 routing), you'll need to make sure you ignore **all** files in the routes folder. Otherwise you'll have issues, since the default convention tries to process files in the wrong format.

```js
/** @type {import('@remix-run/dev').AppConfig} */
module.exports = {
  ignoredRouteFiles: ['**/*'], // <-- ignore all files (remove the '.')
  serverModuleFormat: 'cjs',
  future: {
    // makes the warning go away in v1.15+
    v2_routeConvention: true,
  },
  routes(defineRoutes) {
    // uses the v1 convention, works in v1.15+ and v2
    return createRoutesFromFolders(defineRoutes);
  },
};
```

Comment: I just add this config to work with v1 convention. But I want to achieve folder organizations with v2. 

It's possible no? Or it's mandatory to have all routes flatten in routes directory?

Cause if you remove the config object future and routes. You will hit 404 in /contacts/:contactId

Comment: You can try it with this stackblitz => https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-xypcq2?file=app%2Froutes%2Fcontacts%2F%24contactId.tsx,app%2Fapp.css,app%2Fdata.ts,app%2Froot.tsx,package.json

Comment: With v2 routing, you can only use folders for colocation, not nested routes. You can use `remix-flat-routes` if you want to to try *hybrid* routes, which allows for nesting. I even have a migration script to move v1 to hybrid. https://github.com/kiliman/remix-flat-routes

Comment: Thanks for you answer but we are agree, this part in the doc doesn't need other lib to be functionnal?

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/file-conventions/routes#folders-for-organization

if I define a folder like that `/contacts/$contactId` and in the last folder I create a file name `route.tsx`. It should work no?

Comment: The route name cannot include `/` so it has to be `contacts.$contactId/route.tsx`

Comment: Ok I understood now. Thanks @kiliman